# Why nested FlatMaps could blow up the stack in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, tail-recursion, trampolines

I am learning the Trampoline trick in Scala by reading this paper [Stackless Scala with Free Monad](http://blog.higher-order.com/assets/trampolines.pdf), by Rúnar Bjarnason. But I got stuck in section 4.3 "An easy thing to get wrong".

One thing makes me confused is how a `f(x)` could directly trigger another inner call given a `FlatMap(x, f)`. The `resume` is already a tail recursion so it must happens in one `resume` call. But all the wrapped functions in `resume` should result a Trampoline instance. So I cannot find a case that the stack could still be blowed up.

Anyone can give an example to explain the "corner case"? Thanks.

=============

This is the background in case you haven't seen the awesome paper:

Scala compiler can only apply a [TCO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization) on a local/final tail position self-call function. So `Trampoline` is brought for transforming the stack to the heap. So in the paper, three instances of `Trampoline` are declared for different usages. `Done` is for wrapping the final result. `More` represents the next step to calculate. And `FlatMap` indicates that there is one more thing to do after the next step calculate. So after defining a `bind` operation to it, `Trampoline` becomes a Monad. See the code below (from the paper) :

```

```
sealed trait Trampoline[+A] {
    final def resume: A = this match {
      case Done(v) => v
      case More(k) => k().resume
      case FlatMap(a, f) => a match {
        case Done(v) => f(v).resume
        case More(k) => (FlatMap(k(), f): Trampoline[A]).resume
        case FlatMap(b, g) => (FlatMap(b, (x: Any) => FlatMap(g(x), f)): Trampoline[A]).resume
      }
    }
  }

  case class More[+A](k: () => Trampoline[A])
    extends Trampoline[A]

  case class Done[+A](v: A)
    extends Trampoline[A]

  case class FlatMap[A, +B](sub: Trampoline[A], k: A => Trampoline[B]) extends Trampoline[B]
```

```

Everything makes sense to me until it said that the nested `FlatMap` could still blow up the stack. And this is why I ask it here.

Comment: This is an interesting question and I think a [MCVE] of the problem illustrated in the paper might help provide an answer (I don't assume people are going to read a 8 page PDF just to answer the question, if they haven't read it already).

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov you are right. I was using my mobile to post the question. Will update the details once I get back to my keyboard. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It gives the answer on the paper:

> There is one more corner case to consider here. It’s now possible for
>   resume to overflow the stack if the left-leaning tower of FlatMaps is
>   taller than the call stack. Then the call f(v) will make the call
>   g(x), which will make another inner call, etc...

Notice the constructor `FlatMap (b , x => FlatMap (g( x), f ))` calls the function immediately

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From my understanding, the `x=>FlatMap(g(x),f)` would not be evaluated immediately. And how could disallowing the FlatMap constructor fix the problem if calling `g` would cause stack overflow?

Comment: Thank you for the thought provoking question.
`k: A => Trampoline[B]` is deferred to when it's called but `sub: Trampoline[A]` is left leaning tower of flatMaps from the paper